# Flip one random bit in integer

Tags: python, binary, bit

I would like to flip one bit in integer. So I have to convert integer to binary, than flip one random bit and than convert it back to integer. How could i do that?

```
# what I want to get:
# num = 8 ... 1000
# new_num = flip_one_bit(num)
# it flips one random bit in 1000 -> 0000 or 1010 or 1100, ...
# returns back it's decimal value 0000 = 0; 1010 = 10
from random import randint

def flip_one_bit(num: int) -> int:
    b_num = bin(num)
    # flip one bit than convert back to integer
    return b_num
```

Side question: Is there any way to convert binary to integer without building my own function (anything built-in)? What's the "good way" of doing this?

Comment: use a [butterfly](https://xkcd.com/378/) but make it more random

Comment: but really it probably is as simple as converting the binary to a string, choosing a random character converting it back to int then `abs(int(random_char) - 1)` to flip it, put it back in place and convert to binary, done

Comment: Start by reading https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=int#int and https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=int#format

Answer (score 2):

No need to work with strings:

```
import random

number = 8

print("Before:\n{} {}\n".format(number, bin(number)))

# flip a single bit
number ^= 1 << random.randint(0, number.bit_length()-1)

print("After:\n{} {}".format(number, bin(number)))
```

Comment: Same, but used `randrange` so didn't need to provide 0 and subtract 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `int` with a `base` parameter to convert a binary string to its corresponding int.

```
>>> import random
>>> def flip_one_bit(num: int) -> int:
...     b_num = bin(num)[2:]
...     flip = random.choice(range(len(b_num)))
...     b_num = b_num[:flip] + str(int(not int(b_num[flip]))) + b_num[flip+1:]
...     return int(b_num, base=2)
...
>>> flip_one_bit(1)
0
>>> flip_one_bit(0)
1
>>> flip_one_bit(4)
5
>>> flip_one_bit(4)
5
>>> flip_one_bit(4)
6
>>> flip_one_bit(4)
0
```